# Accessing a remote APE server

Tags: ape

I am a newbie in APE. I have a linux machine that runs the APE server. I would like my .NET program running in another windows machine to connect to the APE server. How do i do it ? Both the machines are on LAN. I tried to do it by

And i modified my httpd.conf file to give a vhost for local.ape-project.org. And i modified my hosts file to map the IP of the linux machine to local.ape-project.org.

What is happening is that i get an error that i dont have the permission to access APE. I have set the permissions in the remote linux machine too. Has anyone else gone through this situation before ? Any help will be appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running APE on a separate machine than your web server, both webserver and APE must be in the same top-level domain. This is required if you are using XHR streams, long polling, or any other transport method that relies on Ajax same-origin policy.

**Example**

webserver: mywebserver.com

APE server: ape.mywebserver.com

Answer (score 0):

APE is a standalone server. In the default config, it runs on port 6969 of your machine.

This means, it is not part of your (Apache?) web server and you won't have to update your httpd.conf

Maybe try to connect to http://yourmachine:6969/ ?